Power BI Folder Connector file ID
Our financial system creates files in excel format for each project. Each project has a folder and the file for the project is named the same for all projects. When using the folder connector in Power BI I get all the files in all the folders but as the file names are the same I can't tell what file came from what project as there is no ID in the file.  The export can't be changed, I asked. So how can I create a ID within the data set to tell what file/project it came from.
I was thinking of using a Hash but  I don't know if there is built in function for that.

There is no inbuilt function for hashing in PowerBI you can simply use the folder path column in the folder step to create a unique ID combining the file name as well.

You can split the path by a delimiter "\" and use different parts of the folder to create a unique ID

